# Заменить scene в главном Stage

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

Как изменять саму `scene` в класе контролере. Ведь `Stage` создается в `main` класе, и не могу до нее достучатся.
Класс `main` :

```
@Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Контроллер класс :

```
@FXML
    private void pressRegistration() {
        try {
            Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/registration.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

По клику на кнопку, создается еще одно окно(`Stage`). Как достучатся до текущего `Stage` (которий в `main`), и визвать метод `setScene()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передать в контроллер экземпляр Stage.
Только нужно немного изменить метод start:

```
    @Override
        public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//Создаем загрузчика
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/login.fxml""));
//Загружаем (место AnchorPane должна быть главная панель твоего fxml):
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
//Теперь мы можем получить экземпляр контроллера для root (вместо MyController - Имя класса контроллера):
MyController controller = loader.getController();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage = new Stage();
//теперь передаем экземпляр Stage в контроллер:
controller.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
```

Соответственно, в класс-контроллер нужно добавить поле Stage primaryStage и сеттер для него.